# How to use crossdomain.xml for my flash project...?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, crossdomain.xml

This drives me crazy...I am trying to build a youtube player with flash and everytime I load a video, there is a runtime security sandbox error..I already put crossdomain.xml in my root server http://mysite.com but I am still getting the errors...Do I miss something? Do I have to load it into my flex project??Thanks for the reply...

My crossdomain.xml

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
    <cross-domain-policy>
       <allow-access-from domain="*.youtube.com"/>
        <allow-access-from domain="s.ytimg.com"/>
    </cross-domain-policy> 
 -->
```

**Edit**: 20100811T0723; this is the actual XML from http://popslinger.org/crossdomain.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-    policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: The content isn't actually commented out in the live file like in your post, is it? (`<!--`)

Comment: no its not....it really drives me crazy....
this is my site

http://popslinger.org/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get a lot of errors too but they generally seem to be on YouTube's side

Here's an example:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3' tried to access 
incompatible context 'http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swf/apiplayer3-vfl181412.swf'
```

As you can see, these are both YouTube domains

So I had a look at YouTube's own crossdomain policy files. It turns out that those files need to be updated. Read the following:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_security_changes_02.html#head1

Here is the policy file from s.ytimg.com

```
<cross-domain-policy> 
  <allow-access-from domain="*" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

which throws the following warning

Warning: Domain s.ytimg.com does not specify a meta-policy.  Applying default meta-policy 'master-only'.  This configuration is deprecated.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files to fix this problem.

and here's what it should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Here's another warning:

Warning: Domain video-stats.video.google.com does not explicitly specify a meta-policy, but Content-Type of policy file http://video-stats.video.google.com/crossdomain.xml is 'text/x-cross-domain-policy'.  Applying meta-policy 'by-content-type'.

It looks like YouTube should look into this, all these warnings and security error messages are pretty annoying.

Practically speaking, have a look at the errors, if your domain name doesn't appear anywhere, your crossdomain file is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how crossdomain files are designed to work. You having a crossdomain file on your server does absolutely nothing to allow Flash to retrieve data from YouTube. Also, are you retrieving the AS3 Chromeless Player such that you abide by the terms of service or are you URL scraping to ultimately retrieve the mp4/flv?

Comment: The questioner should read this. When site A loads a file from site B, the only crossdomain policy involved is the one on site B.

Answer (score 2):

Page Not Found - 404 Error Page
The page you are looking for (http://mysite.com/crossdomain.xml) is not here.

Make sure your web server is configured to dispense XML files.  IIS does not, by default.  Steps to enable it can be found here: http://dannythorpe.com/2008/03/16/serving-rss-on-iis/

Comment: My real site is 

http://popslinger.org/crossdomain.xml

mysite.com is just an example..

Comment: ok, the file loads for me now.  It's just empty.  See Juan Pablo's answer.

Comment: It's not comment out....if you check the source in your browser..you should be able to see it right?

Comment: It's right in the browser, but the code you put in your question contains comments.

Answer (score 2):

If that's your actual XML file, it seems it's commented out.

Remove this:

```
<!--
```

and this:

```
-->
```

PS: Ok, the file can be loaded and has content. Maybe your problem is somewhere else?

What this file does is granting any swf served from any `youtube.com` subdomain or the domain `s.ytimg.com` permission to load data from `popslinger.org`. This has a chance of working if your problems are caused by content served from youtube trying to access data served from your domain. Is that the case?