# Security issue for cross domain access

Tags: php, flash

i have a upload script made in flash with a callback to a php file. In this state anybody can send post request to the php script and can upload malicious files.
I want to restrict the access only to the server which host the flash and php files.

I have stored a key into a text file and change the file permission, but then only the php can access the file and get the secret and no flash. Because flash reads the file by a get request and if i restrict the access i see 403 forbidden access.

If you have any ideas please advice what should i do, thanks.

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454372/how-to-use-crossdomain-xml-for-my-flash-project

Comment: I was but with no help, i still access the php script and upload files from other domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control what people will submit to the script.

You can use [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) to prevent Mallory tricking Alice into submitting malicious data (which will help if you use user credentials so "being Alice" makes a difference), but you can't stop Mallory from simply submitting whatever she likes.

You need to have some kind of moderation and/or malicious file detection and/or restrictions on who (authorised users) can use the service.